# Using Django's class based views to create a list of multiple objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

What's the correct way to extend django's class based views to display a page with a series of  list objects.

Does it make sense to create a ListView class for one of the objects and then pass the data for the other object lists in the get_context function?

What's the 'right' way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just write a custom class view that inherits from the [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/#templateview) and put your logic in the get_context_data method.

Comment: Agreed. Unless one of the object lists is more important than the others, then subclassing `TemplateView` makes more sense.

Comment: Actually - a follow up question - how would you access the context data in the template? I tried context['blah'] = ... and then doing something like {% for b in blah %} in my template but that doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you overwritten `get_context_data` and made sure to return a dictionary containing blah?